# commnand to get random no 92 or 93 in shellscript

Tags: bash, shell, random

for example we are getting 2 digit no using command (((RANDOM % 10) +10))
then how we exact no 92 or 93 form random no`enter code here`
echo $(((RANDOM%10)+10))

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
echo $(( 92 + RANDOM % 2 ))
```

to get only the numbers 92 or 93.

Basically, the rule is

```
$(( X + RANDOM % Y ))
```

gives you the numbers between X and X + Y - 1.